# [PHP][XML] SimpleXML children() returns only one child

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the children in a XML file via PHP which looks like this:

```
<root>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <menu>
        <Stammdaten>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>0</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test121</id>
                <diconr>1</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test12</id>
                <diconr>1</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>10622</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>10707</diconr>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id>Test1</id>
                <diconr>10707</diconr>
            </item>
        </Stammdaten>
    </menu>
</root>
```

And I want to loop through all "item", but when I do

```
echo $xml->menu[0]->Stammdaten->children()->asXML();
```

It only returns the first item and nothing more. Can anyone here tell me what I am doing wrong?

Greetz,

Comment: A well formed XML document must only have one root node and since `asXML` must return a well-formed XML document it just returns one node. You could use `$xml->menu[0]->Stammdaten->asXML()` but then you'd have `<Stammdaten>` as root node.

Comment: The XML is much larger with more nodes, I just made it smaller for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`children()` returns an iterator, so you use it like:

```
foreach ($xml->menu[0]->Stammdaten->children() as $child)
    echo $child->asXML();
```